# How can I modify the "Password policy constraints" text?

Tags: 7, forms

I'm looking for the easiest possible way to modify or alter the password policy constraints error text. The following is the default the users see.

> The password does not include enough variation to be secure.
> Password must contain characters of at least 3 different types  (lowercase, uppercase, digit or punctuation).
> Password must contain at least one digit.
> Password must be at least 8 characters in length.
> Password must contain at least one lowercase character.
> Password must contain at least one punctuation (not whitespace or an alphanumeric) character.
> Password must contain at least one uppercase character.

I would like to modify it to the following text.

> Password must:
> • Be at least 8 characters
> • Have at least one lowercase character
> • Have at least one uppercase character
> • Have at least one digit
> • Have at least one punctuation character

Would this be possible using `hook_form_alter()` or other methods?

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**

Of course there is a [module](https://www.drupal.org/project/password_policy) for that.

Actually, more than one:

https://www.cmsdrupal.com/blog/how-implement-custom-password-policy-drupal
https://dev.acquia.com/blog/password-policies-and-drupal/03/04/2017/17856

**Longer answer:**

Since you don't just want to change the policy (you want to change the form markup too) you might also need to use `hook_form_user_login_block_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)`.